# Firebase Login error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-home

1) Now I am facing issue with firebase. After one month, I am trying to deploy new code using command “firebase deploy –only function” in command prompt. I got below error

```
    Error: Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid. Please run firebase login --reauth

For CI servers and headless environments, generate a new token with firebase login:ci
```

Then I have executed  `“firebase login –reauth”` , I got below comments

```
    “? Allow Firebase to collect anonymous CLI usage and error reporting information? Yes

Visit this URL on any device to log in:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=563584335869-fgrhgmd47bqnekij5i8b5pr03ho849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email%20openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloudplat
formprojects.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffirebase%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&response_type=code&state=430670875&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Floca
lhost%3A9005

Waiting for authentication...”
```

It opened in new browser. In their , i  have selected  my google account and pressed “allow” button. I am getting firebase login failure error in browser.

```
“Oops!
Firebase CLI Login Failed
The Firebase CLI login request was rejected or an error occurred. Please run firebase login again or contact support if you continue to have difficulty logging in
“
```

After this I have executed command “ `firebase login`” in  command prompt,  I got response as “Already logged in as thirus.selvam.2007@gmail.com”. Once again I have tried “`firebase deploy –only functions`” , I got same error.

I didn’t get any errors on last month, How to resolve this error?

2) After these error, i have planned to create another test project using **Google cloud** please find the response in the response in command prompt

```
C:\app\Google Home\test\TestingSetup>gcloud init
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Settings from your current configuration [testsetup] are:
core:
  disable_usage_reporting: 'True'

Pick configuration to use:
 [1] Re-initialize this configuration [testsetup] with new settings
 [2] Create a new configuration
 [24] Switch to and re-initialize existing configuration: [samplets6]
 [25] Switch to and re-initialize existing configuration: [three-door-3456]
Please enter your numeric choice:  2

Enter configuration name. Names start with a lower case letter and
contain only lower case letters a-z, digits 0-9, and hyphens '-':  testingsetup
Your current configuration has been set to: [testingsetup]

You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
  gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...\
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Have you tried to change the network?

Comment: It sounds like the problem's either with your Google account or perhaps the project itself. I'd recommend you jump to step #3 (https://firebase.google.com/support/) and file a ticket with Google support so that an engineer can check your account and your project and explain what's going on /Googler.

Comment: This one is working project, i didn't made any change. i will create ticket